# Swift2.0 CoreData issue on NSFetchRequest

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

This is a code snippet of me trying to fetch data from coredata. I tried to fetch data and checked using breakpoint and there was NO data fethed! The code is in swift2. Any suggestions would be appreciated.  I defined a struct constants where I defined all the constants. gate is a string type defined in nsmanagedobject class. The snippet is a part of viewDidLoad() method.

```
let context: NSManagedObjectContext? = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext!
let TPTodayFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: Constants.CoreDataEntities.TPTodayCoreDataEntity)

do {
let patroDaily = try context!.executeFetchRequest(TPTodayFetchRequest) as! [TPToday]
for patroEntity in patroDaily {
print(patroEntity.gate)

}
}
catch { print("error") }
```

Answer (score 0):

Except for cumbersome variable naming, and unfortunate indentation, your code is fine and should work.

You will have to investigate if you have indeed saved the data you are expecting to find. For example, you could have the program log the documents directory URL after which you could examine the sqlite file with the `sqlite3` command line tool.

Comment: I did that, there is data that is fetched from a json request and has been successfully stored in coredata. I used 'datum' to check into the sqlite file after the json response was saved to coredata.